# Regex for finding file name

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create the regex to match the following cases:

`myFile.txt` or `myFile(1).txt`

but don't match to this this:

`myFile WithSimilarName.txt`

here's my attempt:

`@"({fileName}\(d+\)\.txt)|({fileName}.txt)"`

Comment: What does `myFile WithSimilarName.txt` even mean? whats the difference between this and the first two, is it the space?

Comment: Try [`@"^{fileName}(?:\(\d+\))?\.txt$"`](https://regex101.com/r/8y8xkm/1). Note you missed ``\`` before `d` and a ``\`` before `.`. Remove `^` and `$` if you do not need a whole string match.

Comment: for example:  I want "cup.txt"  I do not want "cup large.txt"

Comment: You don't want to match a filename with a space in it?

Comment: Please don't be that guy: "I don't know what I want but if I see it I will tell you". Tell us **why** you don't want to match that "myfile withsimilarname.txt" filename, not **that** you don't want to match it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to match a file name that has `fileName` and then an optional digit sequence inside parentheses ending with `.txt`.

Your pattern can be formed in the following way:

```
$@"{Regex.Escape(fileName)}(?:\(\d+\))?\.txt"
```

If you need a whole string match, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8y8xkm/1)).

A visual diagram generated by the [jex.im/regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=myFile(%3F%3A%5C(%5Cd%2B%5C))%3F%5C.txt):

[image]

Here,

- `{Regex.Escape(fileName)}` - a `fileName` variable that will get interpolated and all special chars will be escaped with `Regex.Escape`
- `(?:\(\d+\))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\(` - a literal `(`
  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\)` - a literal `)`
- `\.txt` - a `.txt` sequence.

Comment: I've found regexper.com to be a helpful tool for visualizing regex patterns like these. Here's your example: https://regexper.com/#fileName(%3F%3A%5C(%5Cd%2B%5C))%3F%5C.txt

Note that I replaced `{Regex.Escape(fileName)}` with just the string `fileName`.

Comment: @Donut https://jex.im/regulex and http://debuggex.com also provide regex diagrams.